# Using select by attributes in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, warning-000117

**Summary of my problem:**

When I use the select by attributes option directly from the attribute table, my query works perfectly, however, if I run the exact same query from the ModelBuilder. It doesn't select any of the features I want.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug within ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5?

This even happens when I save my query and open it from the ModelBuilder.

**Some more background:**

- I try to do a query based on a column that contains the building name
- If the building name of the attribute contains the word "MRT", the feature should be selected. I use the "contains the text" MRT query.
- I am selecting about 200 out of 60000 features when I use the select by attributes tool within the attribute table. I select 0 features when I do the same within the ModelBuilder.

[image: it works when running the query from the attribute table]

[image: I use the exact same query within the model builder]

[image: However... 0 selections when using the model builder]

Comment: My own guess is that this is a bug, but I am not sure. It seems like Model Builder is not capable of doing queries with upper case letters. It keeps changing MRT back to mrt. I guess it doesn't find any matches because the text is all upper case in the attributes.

Comment: What's the source of your data, is it some SDE layer? This is a basic query and I certainly never observed such behaviour whilst I was using 2.9

Comment: @Hornbydd, thanks for taking the time to answer! It is a feature class stored in a GDB so I don't think it is an SDE? (I am not familiar with SDE's).

Comment: Try simplifying the group layer and layer name, don't have spaces, colon characters or any other non alphabet characters?

Comment: @Hornbydd, thanks. I tried this, but it is also not working. Also changing the text to lower case and running the SQL query again doesn't work.

Comment: Try creating a dummy dataset, unrelated to your current arcpro project, can you replicate the same issue?